# Custom Query breaking WP admin

Tags: wordpress

I have this simple custom query that loops through my custom post type.

It is inside the plugins folder, activated, and is turned into a shortcode, which works perfectly.

The shortcode displays everything like it should. HOWEVER:

When i go to edit the page, I get a quick white page with the query results in it, then the editing admin page opens. And then my admin bar is also completely seperated from the left side.

And then when pressing on "edit", it gives me an error saying "Updating failed. Response is not a valid JSON-response".

This is driving me insane, I have done multiple of these before, but not for some reason my entire admin breaks just from a simple loop. What am i missing?

Thank you for your time!

```
function show_ambassadors($atts) {

$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'ambassadorer',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'posts_per_page' => 8,
    'orderby' => 'title',
    'order' => 'ASC'
);

$loop = new WP_Query($args);

?>

    <div class="ambassador-container">

<?php

if($loop->have_posts()) {

while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); 

    $thumbnail = get_post_thumbnail_id($post);
    $image = wp_get_attachment_image_url($thumbnail, "thumbnail");
    $categories = get_the_terms( $post->ID, 'category' );

?>

<div class="ambassador-inner-container">
    <div class="ambassador-image" style="background-image: url('<?php echo $image ?>'); background-size: cover; background-repeat: no-repeat;"></div>
    <h3 class="ambassador-title"><?php print the_title();  ?></h3>
    <h4 class="ambassador-category"><?php foreach($categories as $cats) {echo ($cats->name);} ?></h4>
</div>

<?php 

endwhile;
}

?>

</div>
<?php 
}

add_shortcode('showamb', 'show_ambassadors');
```

Comment: I don't know if this has to do with your problem, but I think here: `print the_title(); ` you can omit "print" - `the_title(); ` alone should be sufficient. Or actually, you could even write that whole line line as `<?php the_title( '<h3 class="ambassador-title">', '</h3>' ); ?>`

Answer (score 1):

When using the `the_post()` method of `WP_Query`, you manipulate global variables that are used by the “[main WordPress loop](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/the-loop/)”.

You need to use the [`wp_reset_postdata`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_reset_postdata/) function in order to restore those global variables:

```
if($loop->have_posts()) {

    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

    [...]

    endwhile;
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Comment: Hey sorry for not including it for some reason but I had that as well at the exact same spot. Same problem. 

What I am doing now is redoing the query part, and storing everything inside of a variable and returning that instead. Seems to ahve remove the error but now instead I have to hassle with variables inside of a variable etc. Thank you for your reply!